# WooCommerce Shop Page Category Display with multiple category per product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, categories

In my woocommerce store all of my products are organized in two categories.

My problem is on the shop page, the category is displayed above the name of each product, but while clicking on category name it displays the category name that comes first alphabetically. I need that the category name must be same of that we have clicked rather then displaying alphabetically.

Any idea on how this might be accomplished. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give a URL for your site?

Comment: If you are only going to display a single category, you might want to only assign a single category. It is going to be difficult for the code to determine which category you mean to display.... though I think you could get somewhere with adding query vars to links and then processing those query vars on the next page.